# Override Dialog dismiss() with new AlphaAnimation

Tags: java, android, animation, dialog, dismiss

So right now by default the Dialog is doing this zoomin fade out effect when it gets dismissed with `dialog.dismiss();`

how can i override it to be my own Animation?

```
AlphaAnimation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setDuration(600);
view.setAnimation(fadeOut);
view.startAnimation(fadeOut);
```

EDIT:

Thanks to [the answer bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18940569/1310974) i was able to figure it out. Instead of modifying the dismissal, i did the animation then dismissed it like so.

```
public void fadeOutHUD(View view) {
        AlphaAnimation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        fadeOut.setDuration(800);
        view.setAnimation(fadeOut);
        view.startAnimation(fadeOut);
        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }

public void dismissHUD() {
        fadeOutHUD(findViewById(R.id.progressHud));
    }
```

And called it like so `dialog.dismissHUD();`

Comment: Where are you getting the view to fade out? I am trying to access the whole dialog as a view so I can fade it out like here, but I have only managed to get the dialog's content to fade (without the overlay background and white border).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need to override the `Dialog.dismiss()`

> You just animate the dialog as you wanted and at the end of animation,
>   dismiss it.

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: then how would i call the dismissing to tell it to call the animation?

Comment: Figured it out, you were so right, i'll update my question to provide a more detailed solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 7):

You will need to make use of

`dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations` flag to override the enter and exit/ dismiss animations.

This blog post explains to override the animation very well :
http://flowovertop.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-alert-dialog-with-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

Extend the `Dialog` class (it is recommended you use `DialogFragment`) and override its `dismiss()` using your own custom `Animation`.

Comment: I did this and the Dialog just got stuck in a loop of showing, and would no go away, however it would flicker the animation like it was dismissing but then coming back immediately. Also i cant use a DialogFragment, when i do that it doesnt allow me to use `findViewById()`